# use struct value in if statement in solidity

Tags: if-statement, struct, solidity

my code generates a list of how many referrals an address has...It correctly generates the numbers for the total referrals and referrals by level...How can I take the value of total referrals so I can use its value in an if totaltransfers > ? statement?

```
    struct User {
    bool referred;
    address referred_by;
}

struct Referal_levels {
    uint256 level_1;
    uint256 level_2;
    uint256 level_3;
    uint256 level_4;
    uint256 _totalreferred;
}

mapping(address => Referal_levels) public refer_info;
mapping(address => User) public user_info;
    
    
    function lotteryStart() public {
        require (lotteryActive == false, "lottery already active");
        lotteryActive = true;
        lotterystartTime = now;
    }

    function enter(address ref) public payable  {
        require(ref != msg.sender, " You cannot refer yourself ");

        user_info[msg.sender].referred_by = ref;
        user_info[msg.sender].referred = true;

        address level1 = user_info[msg.sender].referred_by;
        address level2 = user_info[level1].referred_by;
        address level3 = user_info[level2].referred_by;
        address level4 = user_info[level3].referred_by;
        address totalreferred = user_info[level4].referred_by;

        if ((level1 != msg.sender) && (level1 != address(0))) {
            refer_info[level1].level_1 += 1;
            refer_info[level1]._totalreferred += 1;
        }
        if ((level2 != msg.sender) && (level2 != address(0))) {
            refer_info[level2].level_2 += 1;
            refer_info[level2]._totalreferred += 1;
        }
        if ((level3 != msg.sender) && (level3 != address(0))) {
            refer_info[level3].level_3 += 1;
            refer_info[level3]._totalreferred += 1;
        }
        if ((level4 != msg.sender) && (level4 != address(0))) {
            refer_info[level4].level_4 += 1;
            refer_info[level4]._totalreferred += 1;
                            }
```

Comment: *I meant totalreferred not totaltransfers

Comment: Do you want to retrieve the _totalreferred value inside Referal_levels struct right?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I figured it out. The solution was

  reftotalRefered = refer_info[ref]._totalreferred;

Comment: But, yea, I wanted a way to get the value of _totalreffered and use it in an if  _totalreffered > statement.